# How to expand variable value to build a

Tags: jq

Sorry if this is included somewhere, looked for a good 30-60 minutes for something along these lines.  I am sure I just missed something! Total jq nub!

Basically I am trying to do a `pick` operation that is dynamic.  My thought process was to do something like this:

```sh
pickJSON() {
  getSomeJSON | jq -r --arg PICK "$1" '{ $PICK }'
}

pickJSON "foo, bar"
```

but this produces

```
{ "PICK": "foo, bar" }
```

Is there a way to essentially ask it to expand shell-style?

---

#### Desired Result:

```sh
pickJSON() {
  getSomeJSON | jq -r --arg PICK "$1" '{ $PICK }'
  # perhaps something like...
  # getSomeJSON | jq -r --arg PICK "$1" '{ ...$PICK }'
}

pickJSON "foo, bar"
```

```
{ "foo": "foovalue", "bar": "barvalue" }
```

> Note that I am new to `jq` and i just simplified what i am doing - if the syntax is broken that is why :-D my actual implementaiton has a few pipes in there and it does work if i dont try to pick the values out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fairly long experimentation phase trying to make this work, I finally came up with what seems like a feasible and reliable solution without the extremely unsettling flaws that could come from utilizing `eval`.

To better highlight the overall final solution, I am providing a bit more of the handling that I am currently working with below:

#### Goal

1. Grab a secret from [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)
2. Parse the returned JSON, which looks like this:

```
{
  "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:MyTestDatabaseSecret-a1b2c3",
  "Name": "MyTestDatabaseSecret",
  "VersionId": "EXAMPLE1-90ab-cdef-fedc-ba987EXAMPLE",
  "SecretString": "{\n  \"username\":\"david\",\n  \"password\":\"BnQw&XDWgaEeT9XGTT29\"\n}\n",
  "VersionStages": [
    "AWSPREVIOUS"
  ],
  "CreatedDate": 1523477145.713
}
```

3. Run some modifications on the JSON string received and pick only the statically requested keys from the secret
4. Set and export those values as environment variables

#### Script

```sh
# Capture a AWS Secret from secretsmanager, parse the JSON and expand the given
# variables within it to pick them from the secret and return given portion of 
# the secret requested.
# @note similar to _.pick(obj, ["foo", "bar"])
getKeysFromSecret() {
  aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "$1" \
    | jq -r '.SecretString | fromjson' \
    | jq -r "{ $2 }"
}

# Uses `getKeysFromSecret` to capture the requested keys from the secret
# then transforms the JSON into a string that we can read and loop through
# to set each resulting value as an exported environment variable.
#
## Transformation Flow:
#   { "foo": "bar", "baz": "qux" } 
# --> 
#   foo=bar
#   baz=qux 
# --> 
#   export foo=bar
#   export baz=qux
exportVariablesInSecret() {
  while IFS== read -r key value; do
    if [ -n "$value" ]; then 
      export "${key}"="${value}";
    fi
  done < <(getKeysFromSecret "$1" "$2" | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value')
}
```

#### Example JSON

```
{
  ...othervalues
  "SecretString": "{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"baz\": \"qux\"}"
}
```

#### Example Usage

```sh
exportVariablesInSecret MY_SECRET "foo, bar"
echo $foo
# bar
```

#### Some Notes / Context

1. This is meant to set a given set of values as variables so that we aren't just setting an entire arbitrary JSON object as variables that could possibly cause issues / shadowing if someone adds a value like "path" to a secret
2. A critical goal was to absolutely never use `eval` to prevent possible injection situations.  Far too easy to inject things otherwise.
3. Happy to see if anyone has a nicer way of accomplishing this.  I saw many people recommending the use of `declare` but that sets the var to the local function scope only so its essentially useless.

---

Thanks to @cas https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413917/308550 for getting me on the right track!